# Countdown and local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, countdown

I don't know very well JavaScript but i must use it in my project.

I need countdown timers which after refresh page don't stop, not cleared and shown all time.

After press button you are redirect to other page, countown  start ant button have '`disable` value. After countdown time, button automatically must have `enable` value.

Here is my project: http://licznikii.cba.pl/dopostu/

In my first version everything works well but not after refresh page. Countdowns are cleared.

In my second version I used `LocalStorage` and it works well to but not much that I won't. After refresh page countowns are hidden. After countdown time button not have automatically `enable` value but after refreshpage. After refresh page after countdown time everything are showed good.

Please Help

Comment: In your second version, You have to get Timer Values from localStorage and on Page load you have to set an timer which have the value stored into the localStorage. After Setting up contents start the timer with the specified time(fetched from localStorage).

Comment: Thank's for sugestions but I completly don't know how I can do it.. My javaScript skills is veery small. In this countdowns somoene helped me.

Comment: Have fun with your solution and greetings to poland :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying your second-version it works. I've tested it in all browsers. Sorry for not code-refactoring, but I think you cope with this now :)

```
<!-- --------------------------------------------------------    SECOND VERSION -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#defaultCountdown3').countdown({until: 0, onTick: highlightLast5});

    var teraz = Date.now();
    var zapisanyCzas = localStorage.getItem("defaultCountdown3");

    if (zapisanyCzas !== null && teraz < +zapisanyCzas) {

        var restTime = secDiff(teraz, +zapisanyCzas);
        console.log(restTime);

        $("#YourButton3").prop('disabled',true);
        $('#defaultCountdown3').removeClass('highlight').countdown('option', {until: Math.round(restTime), onExpiry: countdownFinished});

    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("defaultCountdown3");
    }

    function highlightLast5(periods) {
    if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) === 5) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
      }
    }

    $('#YourButton3').click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem("defaultCountdown3", Date.now() + 60 * 1000);
        $('#defaultCountdown3').removeClass('highlight').countdown('option', {until: 60, onExpiry: countdownFinished});
        $("#YourButton3").prop('disabled',true)
    });

    function countdownFinished(){
        // Finished - disable your button
         localStorage.removeItem("defaultCountdown3");
        $("#YourButton3").prop('disabled',false)
    }

    function secDiff(start, end){
      var diff = Math.abs(start-end);
      return (diff/1000);
    }

 });
</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#defaultCountdown4').countdown({until: 0, onTick: highlightLast5});

    var teraz = Date.now();
    var zapisanyCzas = localStorage.getItem("defaultCountdown4");

    if (zapisanyCzas !== null && teraz < +zapisanyCzas) {

        var restTime = secDiff(teraz, +zapisanyCzas);
        console.log(restTime);

        $("#YourButton4").prop('disabled',true);
        $('#defaultCountdown4').removeClass('highlight').countdown('option', {until: Math.round(restTime), onExpiry: countdownFinished});


    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("defaultCountdown4");
    }

    function highlightLast5(periods) {
    if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) === 5) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
      }
    }

    $('#YourButton4').click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem("defaultCountdown4", Date.now() + 120 * 1000);
        $('#defaultCountdown4').removeClass('highlight').countdown('option', {until: 120, onExpiry: countdownFinished});
        $("#YourButton4").prop('disabled',true)
    });

    function countdownFinished(){
        // Finished - disable your button
         localStorage.removeItem("defaultCountdown4");
        $("#YourButton4").prop('disabled',false)
    }

    function secDiff(start, end){
      var diff = Math.abs(start-end);
      return (diff/1000);
    }

 });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried...tried....and nothing... :/  Actually it look like: http://licznikii.cba.pl/dopostu/index2.php . Everything works good until I refresh page. I don't know what i'm doing....my JS skills....

Comment: Did you try to pass 60 or 120 or 180 etc. in countdown-function as until-option? Your did right. this condition looks right: zapisanyCzas !== null && teraz < +zapisanyCzas. Which check datetime of localstorage lies in the future and if so it should set until-option accordingly. But within this condition you calulate the difference in milliseconds and in your functions you pass 60 or 120. So may be this causes the timer not to count down again after page-refresh. But the timer is started when some button is clicked furthermore it tries to start timer again. Do not give up you are almost done :)

Comment: Look, in this situation on second version http://licznikii.cba.pl/dopostu/ countdowns works good even if i refresh page but countdown are hidden. eg: I click first buuton, countown start with 60 sec, i refresh page after 10 second - countown is hide, I refresh after 60 sec-countown is showed. That means countdown works. I need countdown show actually time all time. I think I must showed data from local storage but i dont know how...

Comment: What do you mean by "must showed data from local storage"? I did not write that counddown is not working but I wrote that until-property is wrong.

Comment: Sorry my english is not the best ;) Im from Poland. I mean when countdown are hidden after refresh page i should show it from localstorage in my div? really I dont know, I have confused mind of this work and my head are hot...

Comment: No problem. I extended my answer, it's on top of it. Hope this helps more.

Comment: WOOW! I'm really really very very grateful for this :)))) I'm DONE! You are the best master king super cool maan! :)) Have you BTC adress?

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry no, but you can reach me within my deposited stackoverflow-email address. For security reasons I do not post it in here ;)